# Display another row in php if a string matches

Tags: php

I have an SQL table that has a list of users, their states and phone numbers such as:

```
User01 Online +27121
User02 Offline +02123
User03 Online +02212
```

I am using php to display only users and their states

```
<?php

//Database details
$servername = "servername";
$username = "uid";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "myDB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql_GetURL = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT UserName, UserState FROM Users");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_GetURL)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['UserName'] . " " . $row['UserState'] . "</td></tr> <br>"; 
    }

?>
```

Now I want to extend my code to check if any user's state is "online" then echo their phone number such as:

```
if($row['UserState'] == "Online"){
        echo $row['PhoneNumber']; //This is never shown
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
```

The if statement is never true, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `PhoneNumber` to the `SELECT` list, otherwise it won't be in `$row`.

Comment: `if( $row['UserState'] == "Online" ){...`

Comment: `echo "$row['PhoneNumber'];` should be `echo $row['PhoneNumber'];`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in the query itself.

```
SELECT UserName, UserState, IF(UserState = 'Online', PhoneNumber, '') AS PhoneNumber FROM Users;
```

Then just display `$row['PhoneNumber']` in the table. It will be blank for the offline users.